# jQuery UI slider example code copy pasted and doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I needed a range slider and I couldn't get it to work, so I pasted whole example code into html file and it still doesn't work. Any help of what I could do to fix it? With this code copy pasted into html I just get a blank website. .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it helps you my friend:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

you can find more example in this page [https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range]

complete html is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
  <p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I created new html, pasted those 2 links and 2 scripts into head file; label, input, slider div and function script into body, but all I get is price range, it doesn't show the slider. I don't know if I'm doing something dumb, but I've been sitting on this problem for like 3 hours.

Comment: where you add the script ? you must add your script end of your code ... after body

Comment: oh sorry in <link> address miss `https:` you must reference to this URL : https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: you miss `https:` before `//code` ... it solved ...